# Prove (a ∧ b) · c does NOT equal 0 if and only if a, b and c are linearly independent

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, orthogonality, independence

> Prove that 
>   $(a ∧ b)\cdot c\ne0\iff a, b$ and $c$ are linearly independent,
>   where $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^3$.

In the first part of the question, I proved that $(a ∧ b)$ is orthogonal to $a$ and to $b$, so I'm thinking this may come in useful?

I have worked out the following:
$$(a ∧ b)\cdot c = a_1(a_2b_3-b_2a_3) + a_2(a_3b_1-b_3a_1) + a_3(a_1b_2-b_1a_2)$$
where $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ etc.

I've also been able to prove that if they are not linearly independent (i.e. they are scalar multiples of one another), then $(a ∧ b)\cdot c = 0$, but I'm really stuck on what to do now?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Do *not* work in coordinates! It's easier to take the contrapositive statement. Show that $(a\wedge b)\cdot c = 0$ if and only if $a,b,c$ are linearly *dependent*. [And, also learn what linear dependence means. With three or more vectors, it does *not* mean that the vectors are scalar multiples of one another!!!!]

Comment: Thanks for your help! So I now see that (a ∧ b) = 0 iff a and b are linearly dependent, and therefore a and b must be linearly independent. How do I then see that c must also be linearly independent? Thank you

Comment: Use Ted's hint. If $a, b,$ and $c$ are linearly dependent, then what can you say about $a,$ for instance? Once you write that down, use facts about the cross product to compute $(a \wedge b) \cdot c.$ Conversely, if $(a \wedge b) \cdot c = 0,$ then $c$ is orthogonal to $a \wedge b.$ But $a \wedge b$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b,$ so what can you say about $a, b,$ and $c?$

Answer (score 1):

$a,b,c$ can be written in terms of the unit vectors $e_1=(1,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)$. They span exactly the same space, and therefore $(a\wedge b)\cdot c$ is the exactly the same as for the $e_1,e_2,e_3$ representation, which is never zero.